# Vagrant Puppet apply manifest with wrong environment

Tags: puppet, vagrant, hiera

I use Puppet 3.7 in standard client-server mode, with environments, and using Hiera for data.
I use Vagrant to test the Puppet manifests directly from my Puppet repository.

I recently started to use Hiera and changed my Vagrantfile (and Vagrant directory) to works with it. It now seems to work with Hiera but another problem appears: Vagrant thinks my VM is in environment production when it's in experimental one. (this worked fine before)

The Puppet repository looks like

```
~/code/puppet
└── environments
    ├── experimental
    │   ├── manifests
    │   │   └── site.pp
    │   ├── modules
    │   └── Puppetfile
    ├── production
    │   ├── manifests
    │   │   └── site.pp
    │   ├── modules
    │   └── Puppetfile
    └── testing
        ├── manifests
        │   └── site.pp
        ├── modules
        └── Puppetfile
```

My Vagrant setup is stored in another directory. I have created a symbolic link (ln -s) to ~/code/puppet named puppet in this directory.
The Vagrantfile looks

```
config.vm.define "standalone", primary: true do |config|
    config.vm.box = "debian_wheezy+vbox_jessie+puppet_3.7"
    config.vm.hostname = "standalone.puppet.vagrant"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.10.21"

    config.vm.synced_folder "puppet/hieradata", "/etc/puppet/hieradata"
    config.vm.provision :puppet, :options => ["--yamldir /hieradata"] do |puppet|
        puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/environments/experimental/manifests"
        puppet.manifest_file = "site.pp"
        puppet.module_path = [ "puppet/environments/experimental/modules", "puppet/environments/production/modules", "puppet/modules" ]
        puppet.hiera_config_path = "puppet/hiera.yaml"
    end
  end
```

I imagine that my recent changes following the use of Hiera are not correct to Vagrant, and maybe the hacks (linking puppet code directory) are the cause, but I can't see how this should be organized.

Is there some people who knows this problem and how to solve it?

Thanks

**Update**

I changed

```
puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/environments/#{env}/manifests"
```

and removed puppet.working_directory to have my VM up/provision.

With

```
puppet.module_path = [ "puppet/modules", "puppet/environments/production/modules" ]
```

it seems to let my VM access to production and current env modules, which I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify all options for your puppet run. You can use something like this:

```
srv.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
      puppet.working_directory = "/vagrant/puppet"
      puppet.module_path       = "puppet/modules"
      puppet.manifests_path    = "puppet/manifests"
      puppet.manifest_file     = "site.pp"
      puppet.hiera_config_path = "puppet/hiera.yaml"
      puppet.options           = "--debug --verbose --environment #{env}"
end
```

Which means that your modules are in "puppet/modules/#{env} and your manifests in "puppet/manifests/#{env}. 
Now, "env" is a variable that you can set in your Vagrantfile:

```
env = "production"
```

or: you could put all variables, like "env", in a yaml file and load that.

For reference, you can find all puppet provision options here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/puppet_apply.html

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking to solve a similar issue. I was able to concatenate more than one modulepath by using an Array. So that modulepath will become

`modulepath = ../puppet/environments/dev/modules:../puppet/modules`

Your paths will vary.

My vagrant environment will always be `dev` so I am fine hard-coding this modulepath here.

My Vagrantfile looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos7"
  config.vm.synced_folder("../../puppet/trunk/server/hieradata", "/etc/puppet/hieradata")
  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.environment       = "dev"
    puppet.environment_path  = "../../puppet/trunk/server/environments"
    puppet.hiera_config_path = "../../puppet/trunk/server/hiera.yaml"
    puppet.module_path       = [ "../../puppet/trunk/server/environments/dev/modules", "../../puppet/trunk/server/modules" ]
  end
end
```